# Div-Wrap with Functions.php in Childtheme using Shortcode!

Tags: shortcode

I simply want to create a Shortcode for a simple styled DIV-Wrapper.

At Sites in WordPress i want to add someting like this:

```
[quotehead]Headline text[/quotehead]
...a normal blockquote from wordpress...
```

The Output should be:

```
<div class="block_header">Headline text</div>
```

My function inside `functions.php` (in childtheme) has the following content:

```
/**
 * Function block_header_start
 **/
function block_header_start()
{
    return ('<div class="block_header">');
}

/**
 * Function block_header_end
 **/
function block_header_end()
{
    return ('</div>');
}

add_shortcode('blockhead','block_header_start');
add_shortcode('/blockhead','block_header_end');
```

---

But the output looks like that:

```
<div class="block_header">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <blockquote>...my content of blockquote...</blockquote>
</div>
```

1. Issue: The Words inside the new Wrapper doesn't appears in Frontend!
2. Issue: The Wrapper includes the following blockquote, but the closing [/quotehead] is in front of the blockquote in Backend.?!

---

Is it possible to use only one Shortcode, and wrap the Content that follows, till the end of that line in one function..

Something like the leading # for headers in here or for Markdown files?

Or just the wrapping variant, that works?

Where is my failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortcodes come in two flavors:

```
[shortcodename param1 = value, ..., param-n = value]
```

and

```
[shortcodename param-1 = value, ..., param-n = value]some content[/shortcodename]
```

In both cases, `add_shortcode('shortcodename', 'functionname')` function is identical.

The `functionname()` function's parameters, determine which flavor will be used:

`functionname($atts)` is for shortcode with no closing tag, and
`functionname($atts, $content)` is for shortcode with an arbitrary content, between opening, and closing tags.

In our case, the second type should be used:

```
function my_block_header($atts, $content) {
    return '<div class="block_header">' . $content . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode('blockhead', 'my_block_header');
```

Use as:

```
<blockquote>
    [blockhead]Headline text[/blockhead]
    ... quoted text ...
</blockquote>
```

**Note:** second `add_shortcode`, in your code is unnecessary, and incorrect, as shortcode tag cannot start with `/` character, and one shortcode is enough, to return a division, with both, opening, closing tags. Also, both shortcode functions, in your code, lack mandatory parameters.

Comment: for what is $atts ? $content is clear ;) ..

Comment: `$atts` is an array of shortcode's parameters. It has to be specified, even, if not used.

Comment: thank you.. it works.. but i have the header block outsite the blockquote.. for different styling ;)...

Comment: @FrankP.Walentynowicz nice but no upvote, you never explained what the OP did incorrectly, and how to fix it, your answer could just be copypaste with no learning :(

Comment: @TomJNowell you are right. Quite often, I forget that the answer is not for one person, but for broader audience, with different levels of experience. I'm going to update my answer. +1 for your comment.

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell for your reference. And thanks @ Frank for update your Answer. If I could I vote up twice ;).